# Does the function $V(x,y)=x^2+(y+f(x))^2$ where $f \in C^2(R, R)$ have a isolated minimum at the point $(0, f(0))$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Does the function $V(x,y)=x^2+(y+f(x))^2$ where $f \in C^2(R, R)$ have an isolated minimum at the point $(0, f(0))$?

I was working on an ode problem that involves showing whether the above function has an isolated minimum at the point $x=0 $, $y=f(0)$. Now I don't know if my ability to produce estimates is just rusty or what, but I feel like this should depend on what $f$ is correct? without knowing what $f$ is, I'm not sure if we are able to tell whether $V$ has an isolated minimum at the point $(0, f(0))$.

Comment: Do you mean $V(x,y)=x^2+(y-f(x))^2$?

Comment: @RobertZ , no. But are you saying this works if we had the minus sign instead?

Comment: $V(x,y)=x^2+(y-f(x))^2$ has an isolated minimum at $(0,f(0))$ because $V(0,f(0))=0$ and $V>0$ otherwise ($V$ is the sum of two squares)

Comment: For $V(x,y)=x^2+(y+f(x))^2$ the minimum is $(0,-f(0))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's evaluate the gradient of $V(x,y)=x^2+(y+f(x))^2$:

$$\nabla V = \begin{bmatrix}2x + 2 f'(x)(y+f(x))\\2(y + f(x))\end{bmatrix}.$$

The gradient is null in a stationary point. That is:

$$\begin{cases}
2x + 2 f'(x)(y+f(x)) = 0\\
2(y + f(x)) = 0
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}
2x + 2 f'(x)(y+f(x)) = 0\\
y =-f(x)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}
2x + 2 f'(x)(-f(x)+f(x)) = 0\\
y =-f(x)
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}x = 0\\
y =-f(0)
\end{cases} .$$

Hence, the only candidate to be an isolated minimum is the stationary point $(0, -f(0))$.

Notice that:

$$V(0, -f(0)) = 0^2 + (-f(0) + f(0))^2 = 0$$

and that

$$V(x,y) \geq 0$$

since it is the sum of two squares. Since $V(x,y) = 0 \iff (x,y) = (0, -f(0))$, then $(0, -f(0))$ is an isolated minimum of $V(x,y)$.

Comment: You might want to write that $V(x,y)>0$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,-f(0))$ to show that the minimum is isolated (unless I am messing up with the definition of isolated minimum).

Comment: @LorenzoPompili thanks, you are right.